# Collect data from a table with two level of GROUP BY

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I am trying to collect data from an Oracle database table with `GROUP BY`. and I think that I need two levels of `GROUP BY`, but I do not know how to complete my query.

**I have a STATUS table with millions of statuses this way:**

```
REQUEST    STATUS
-------    -----------
ID      -> REQUEST_ID
...        ID
           STATUS_CODE
           ....
```

**Example how a request flow looks like (STATUS table):**

```
SELECT ... FROM STATUS WHERE REQUEST_ID = 1 ORDER BY ID;

ID      REQUEST_ID  STATUS_CODE  STATUS_ALIAS                       CREATED
1       1           201          REQUEST_SAVED
2       1           204          REQUEST_SIGNATURE_VALID
3       1           210          REQUEST_XML_VALID
4       1           280          REQUEST_ACCEPTED

5       1           310          SENT_TO_SYSTEM_1_FOR_VERIFICATION
6       1           320          SENT_TO_SYSTEM_2_FOR_VERIFICATION
7       1           521          SYSTEM_1_VERIFICATION_ERROR
8       1           511          SYSTEM_2_VERIFICATION_ERROR

24880   1           310          SENT_TO_SYSTEM_1_FOR_VERIFICATION
24881   1           320          SENT_TO_SYSTEM_2_FOR_VERIFICATION
24885   1           620          SYSTEM_1_VERIFICATION_TIMEOUT
24886   1           610          SYSTEM_2_VERIFICATION_TIMEOUT

24887   1           310          SENT_TO_SYSTEM_1_FOR_VERIFICATION
24888   1           320          SENT_TO_SYSTEM_2_FOR_VERIFICATION
.....
```

I would like to collect `REQUEST_ID`s that are in the VERIFICATION state, but not TIMEOUTED yet, like this:

```
24887   1           310          SENT_TO_SYSTEM_1_FOR_VERIFICATION
.....
```

**This is how I select that data:**

```
SELECT REQUEST_ID, STATUS_CODE, MAX(ID) FROM STATUS
GROUP BY REQUEST_ID, STATUS_CODE HAVING STATUS_CODE = 310;

REQUEST_ID  STATUS_CODE  MAX(ID)
1           310          24887
```

This shows properly the `ID` from where I need to filter the grouped STATUS records `REQUEST_ID`, but when I combined this query with an outer `SELECT` to show the `REQUEST_ID`s, it does not work.

**This is my best try so far:**

```
SELECT T1.REQUEST_ID FROM STATUS T1
GROUP BY T1.REQUEST_ID, T1.ID HAVING T1.ID >= (
   SELECT MAX(ID) FROM STATUS T2
   GROUP BY T2.REQUEST_ID, T2.STATUS_CODE
   HAVING T2.STATUS_CODE IN (310, 320) AND NOT IN (610, 620)
);

ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"
```

**UPDATE**

The proplem with the suggested solutons is the following.
Let's suppose that the flow continues this way:

```
24887   1           310          SENT_TO_SYSTEM_1_FOR_VERIFICATION
24888   1           320          SENT_TO_SYSTEM_2_FOR_VERIFICATION

24889   1           460          SYSTEM_2_VERIFICATION_OK
24890   1           510          SYSTEM_1_VERIFICATION_ERROR
```

then if there is no other responses from system 1 within let's say 10 mins, I need to add a timeout for only system 1:

```
24891   1           620          SYSTEM_1_VERIFICATION_TIMEOUT
```

But only one time. That is why the query must filter out 620. Othervise this request-id 1 appears in the result set again despite the timeout flag was set earlier in the previous check run.

**UPDATE 2**

I can write a proper "`WHERE`" condition at Java level and find the requests with `lambda filters` which are in the 'stucked' state, where I need to add the timeout status. But that way I always need to loop through the whole STATUS table from Java and execute my java logic on each `GRUOP BY REQUEST_ID` group. This is bad and time consuming, will run so long, so this solution will not work properly. Maybe I need a stored procedure? That is why I want to have a "super" SQL query which returns with the ID-s of the requests which stucked and I can set the timeut flags for requests with these IDs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might be confused, but I think what you need is just:

```
SELECT REQUEST_ID, STATUS_CODE, MAX(ID) 
  FROM STATUS
 WHERE STATUS_CODE IN (310, 320)
 GROUP BY REQUEST_ID, STATUS_CODE;
```

This `T2.STATUS_CODE IN (310, 320) AND NOT IN (610, 620)` makes no sense since when you specify the status code to be in 310/320 it will for sure not be in 610/620.

Answer (score 0):

In `HAVING T2.STATUS_CODE IN (310, 320) AND NOT IN (610, 620)` the second clause does not add anything as if it is in (310,320) it cannot be in (610,620).
See the dbFiddle link below for schema, testing and other queries.

> ```
> SELECT 
>    REQUEST_ID, 
>    STATUS_CODE, 
>    MAX(ID) AS MAX_ID
>  FROM STATUS
>  WHERE STATUS_CODE IN (310, 320)
>  GROUP BY 
>    REQUEST_ID, 
>    STATUS_CODE;
> ```
>
> ```
> REQUEST_ID | STATUS_CODE | MAX_ID
> ---------: | ----------: | -----:
>          1 |         310 |  24887
>          1 |         320 |  24888
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=606b939e98ab53507858d6ade8483140)*

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle you may use [`LAST`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/LAST.html#GUID-4E16BC0E-D3B8-4BA4-8F97-3A08891A85CC) aggregate function in `HAVING` clause to filter by the final state of the request.

And in all the DBMS you may use `row_number()` to mark the final row and then filter it.

Assuming `ID` column is always incrementing (or replace it with the one that is always incrementing), you'll get:

> ```
> create table t (ID, REQUEST_ID, STATUS_CODE, STATUS_ALIAS)
> as
> select 1, 1, 201, 'REQUEST_SAVED' from dual union all
> select 2, 1, 204, 'REQUEST_SIGNATURE_VALID' from dual union all
> select 3, 1, 210, 'REQUEST_XML_VALID' from dual union all
> select 4, 1, 280, 'REQUEST_ACCEPTED' from dual union all
> select 5, 1, 310, 'SENT_TO_SYSTEM_1_FOR_VERIFICATION' from dual union all
> select 6, 1, 320, 'SENT_TO_SYSTEM_2_FOR_VERIFICATION' from dual union all
> select 7, 1, 521, 'SYSTEM_1_VERIFICATION_ERROR' from dual union all
> select 8, 1, 511, 'SYSTEM_2_VERIFICATION_ERROR' from dual union all
> select 24880, 1, 310, 'SENT_TO_SYSTEM_1_FOR_VERIFICATION' from dual union all
> select 24881, 1, 320, 'SENT_TO_SYSTEM_2_FOR_VERIFICATION' from dual union all
> select 24885, 1, 620, 'SYSTEM_1_VERIFICATION_TIMEOUT' from dual union all
> select 24886, 1, 610, 'SYSTEM_2_VERIFICATION_TIMEOUT' from dual union all
> select 24887, 1, 310, 'SENT_TO_SYSTEM_1_FOR_VERIFICATION' from dual union all
> select 24888, 1, 320, 'SENT_TO_SYSTEM_2_FOR_VERIFICATION' from dual union all
> select 30000, 2, 201, 'REQUEST_SAVED' from dual union all
> select 30001, 2, 204, 'REQUEST_SIGNATURE_VALID' from dual union all
> select 30002, 2, 210, 'REQUEST_XML_VALID' from dual union all
> select 30003, 2, 280, 'REQUEST_ACCEPTED' from dual union all
> select 30004, 2, 310, 'SENT_TO_SYSTEM_1_FOR_VERIFICATION' from dual union all
> select 30005, 2, 320, 'SENT_TO_SYSTEM_2_FOR_VERIFICATION' from dual union all
> select 30006, 2, 521, 'SYSTEM_1_VERIFICATION_ERROR' from dual
> ```

> ```
> select
>   request_id
>   , max(status_alias) keep(dense_rank last order by id asc) as final_status
> from t
> /*To restrict input as much as possible*/
> where status_code >= 310
> group by request_id
> having max(status_code) keep(dense_rank last order by id asc) in (310, 320)
> ```
>
> ```
> REQUEST_ID | FINAL_STATUS                     
> ---------: | :--------------------------------
>          1 | SENT_TO_SYSTEM_2_FOR_VERIFICATION
> ```

> ```
> with a as (
>   select
>     t.*
>     , row_number() over(
>       partition by
>         request_id
>       order by
>         id desc
>     ) as rn
>   from t
>   where status_code >= 310
> )
> select *
> from a
> where rn = 1
>   and status_code in (310, 320)
> ```
>
> ```
>    ID | REQUEST_ID | STATUS_CODE | STATUS_ALIAS                      | RN
> ----: | ---------: | ----------: | :-------------------------------- | -:
> 24888 |          1 |         320 | SENT_TO_SYSTEM_2_FOR_VERIFICATION |  1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=22f90b35171daa4cd5225431c1315fd1)*

Comment: that is one great solution that came up in my mind as well: `status_code >= 310`. The reason why this does not work properly is that the status_codes are not always increasing as the flow continues :( Let's say that status_code numbers were designed not that way.. The ID-s comes from sequence so IDs are increasing continuously. I am trying to ask permission for re-ordering the status_code numbers, but maybe this modification will be not allow because it has an impact on another systems.

Comment: @zappee If you know status codes of interest, then it may be suitable to apply filter by `in (list_of_values)` and then identify the last status etc. But anyway you have to know other request outcomes that you want to filter out.